# How to prove a one to one correspondence.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

We already know that the definition of one to one correspondence between set $A$ and $B$ is as follow:

1. Every element in $A$ corresponds to exactly one element to $B$.
2. Every element in $B$ corresponds to exactly one element to $A$.

Now, the question is that what does corresponds mean, is this a two way relationship?

Example:

Given $A={1,2,3,4,5,\cdots ,50}$ and $B={2,3,4,5,6,\cdots ,51}$

Two prove they are one to one corresponds, we need to show 1. and 2.

1. For element $n\in A,$ the corresponding element in $B$ is $n+1$,
2. For element $n\in B,$ the corresponding element in $A$ is $n-1$,

and we are done.

The question is can I have another correspondence in 2. (only in 2, not 1). Say 51 -1, 50-2, 49-3, etc. Then we also have that Every element in $B$ corresponds to exactly one element to $A$. However, the correspondence are different. Is this valid? If not, when you are proving a one to one correspondence, do you need to show the correspondence is consistent in both 1. and 2.? I think this question is very much related to the definition of correspondence, so I asked this question above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "corresponds to" language is vivid and suggestive, but not quite precise, and in this case it seems to be confusing you. It is better to go back to complete technical definitions, in the style of:

> A **one-to-one correspondence** from $A$ to $B$ is a function $f:A\to B$ such that
>
> 1. For every $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $f(a)=b$ (this is implicit in the concept of a "function", so will often not be stated in so many words), *and*
> 2. For every $b\in B$ there is one and only one $a\in A$ such that $f(a)=b$.

Note that the formula $f(a)=b$ *is the same* in the two prongs, so if $a=1$ goes with $b=2$ in one of them they also go together in the other.

---

Alternatively, to make the definition look more symmetric at the expense as not being quite as conventional, you could say:

> A **one-to-one correspondence** between $A$ and $B$ is a subset $R\subseteq A\times B$ such that
>
> 1. For every $a\in A$ there is exactly one $b\in B$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$, *and*
> 2. For every $b\in B$ there is exactly one $a\in A$ such that $\langle a,b\rangle\in R$.

The important point for the purpose of this question is still that it is the *same* $R$ both parts of the definition say something about.

(This is actually the same definition as the one before, if you use the standard set-theoretic representation of "function").

Comment: So in the example I provided, the correspondence does have to be consistent. But how do you show that the correspondence are consistent rigorously.

Comment: @Kun: How to show that a particular correspondence satisfies the definition depends fundamentally on how you have defined that particular correspondence.

Comment: So what about the example I provided? I am still a bit puzzled by this..

Comment: @Kun: In your example, you would have $f(a)=a+1$, and you then need to prove that for every $b\in B=\{2,3,4,\ldots,51\}$ there is exactly one $a\in A=\{1,2,3,\ldots,50\}$ such that $a+1=b$. This has two parts: First that there is such an $a$ (namely, take $a=b-1$ and argue that this is indeed $\in A$), second that there is only one (if $a_2\ne b-1$, then $a_2+1\ne b$).

Comment: (Oh, and as a prelude to that you must also show that this $f$ is indeed a function from $A$ to $B$, that is, whenever $a\in A$ we have $a+1\in B$).

Comment: Thank you so much! So in many combinatorics problem, people use bijection pretty often. And they are just saying that so and so form a bijection without much of a proof. So they are just simplifying the rigorous proof, right?

Comment: @Kun: In general, outside beginner courses in this material, one can get away with assuming that the reader is able to reconstruct this kind of proofs in his head without needing much about them written down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your time.. A last question, where is bijection formally introduced(with rigor)? What book or what class? I try find something to read.

Comment: @Kun: Virtually every textbook for freshman "introduction to sets, functions and proofs" courses ought to have this. I don't have particular titles to recommend -- when I was at that level myself we were taught from photocopied lecture notes that were not even in English ...